# Configuring Custom JSONDeserializer in Spring Boot 2.3 with MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, xss

I'm trying to add custom json deserializer for filtering certain text (like ,  for xss) in my application with `@JsonComponent`. All works fine until I add `@EnableWebMvc` to my main class. After adding mvc annotation deserialize method of json deserializer is not invoked. `@EnableWebMvc` is required since I upload some data in multipart request.

```java
@JsonComponent
public class Deserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> implements ContextualDeserializer {

        @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException {
        String value = parser.getValueAsString();
            return Jsoup.clean(value, Whitelist.basic()), true);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<String> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        return this;
    }
}
```

This works ->

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

This does not ->

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

So my question is does `@EnableWebMvc` stops custom deserializer from functioning and is whether custom deserializer itself is best practice for such requirement.

Also is there some other of doing this filtering like via spring security.